# How can the AssemblyName class be used for existing Assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

This is another exam related question.

How can I use the `AssemblyName` class to represent an existing
assembly that already exists on disk?

I am talking about from the perspective of using the `AppDomain`'s instance method `.Load()` that takes an `AssemblyName` object as a parameter. I know what MSDN has to say about what the `.Load()` method was designed for; but that aside, I still want to know how to use it.

Comment: So you want to know how to dynamically load an assembly using just its assembly name?

Comment: explain dynamically in this context???

I want to know how to load an existing assembly using an AssemblyName object as shown below (thanks to Hans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I see the question.  But yeah, that can work:

```
  var name = new AssemblyName("System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
  var asm = Assembly.Load(name);
```

Comment: so them details you provide for the constructor those are real details of the assembly you want to load via a AssemblyName object????

if that's true? 

I NEED TO GIVE THAT A GO !!!

Comment: Not sure why you'd think it isn't true.  But I certainly posted the snippet so you could try it for yourself.  Yeah, give it a go.